# How do I save a file to a subfolder of home?

Tags: nautilus, home-directory

My painting app (GIMP) keeps it brushes in a subfolder of `home`.

I want to save a brush I have created in the same place, but the Save File As dialog box can't find `home`.

Comment: Can you please make a screenshot of the "save as" dialogue and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Your home directory is at `/home/your_username/`

Depending on your Ubuntu and Gimp versions, respectively: your home directory is propably represented by your own username (usually in the left pane of file picker dialogs).

Optionally, you can access it by choosing "file system" from the places list (left pane) and navigate to `/home/your_username/your_subdir`. Most file picker dialogs also allow you to edit the path in the location bar (usually at the top, maybe after clicking on it or pressing Strg+L) directly.

Answer (score -1):

Why not save it in any directory, and then open up a terminal and write:

```
mv </path/my_file> <path_for_file_to_be_moved>
```

This will move the file to your wanted location. Example:

```
mv my_brush ~/.brushes/
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is a fine solution to the problem. Please consider explaining your downvotes.